# 12v LiFePo4 battery and external power supply in parallel?

Tags: batteries, charging

I have a project that will be powered by a 12v LiFePo4 battery (probably 6 or 12 Ah) with an "internal bms" (like [this one](https://a.co/d/5bcCKoM)). I would like the ability to connect the project to an external 12v (-ish) power supply when one is available, and have that external supply both charge the battery and power the project (which has a typical draw of < 1A, but may draw up to 10A).

A LiFePo4 battery requires a charging voltage around 14.4v. Can I just run the external power through a regulator to bring it to that voltage, and then connect the battery and input power to a second regulator that brings it to the desired 13.8v to power the load?

One of the goals here is that if the external power source is unable to source the appropriate current, the project would be able to draw from the battery. Connecting things in parallel like this seems like it would allow that to work.

E.g.:

```
                              +-------------+
                              |             |
                              |   Battery   |
                              |             |
                              +-------------+
             +-------------+       |   |           +------------+
             |             |       |   |           |            |
 input + +---+   14.4v     +-------+---------------+ 13.8v      +----+
             |   Regulator |           |           | Regulator  |      Load
       - +---+             +-----------+-----------+            +----+
             +-------------+                       +------------+
```

This relies on the battery to self-manage its charging, and I don't know if that will work. Is this a reasonable configuration? Is there a better way?

---

Looking around, I've found the [Astron BB-30M](https://www.astroncorp.com/bb-30m-battery-backup), which looks like it does almost exactly what I want for SLA batteries. It's not clear if it would be appropriate for LiFePo4 batteries, which don't require a float charge (it also doesn't appear to regulate the output voltage, which is simply input voltage - `0.4v`, and it's far beefier than I need, with a max output current of 30A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that for at least three reasons.

First of all, your diagram will short charging input and power output together, bypassing parts of internal BMS.

Secondly, a BMS is not a charger, and the battery has no internal charger, so batteries can't be charged with a power supply, because it does not understand about charging anything. If someone suggests a CC-CV power supply, it is better but should also not be used because it does not understand when battery is full and does not stop charging. Then if someone suggests that the internal BMS will stop charging when battert is full, that's not true, it will cut when there is already some overcharge, and the battery will degrade every time it is overcharged. And if the BMS breaks, then you have a battery that can explode or start a fire.

Third, the product sales page says this explicitly :

> Please note that this battery should be charged using a LiFePO4 compatible charger, and not a charger for SLA batteries.